# how to install MySql JDBC connector in CENTOS 5 (mysql-connector-java)

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, centos

I try to install the MySQL JDBC connector in CENTOS 5 but it does not work
I try this command

```
 yum install mysql-connector-java
```

but i get this message:

```
 No package mysql-connector-java available.
 Nothing to do
```

this command work in centos 6  but in my VPS I have installed centos 5 32bit but it doesn't works so any suggestion?

so what do I need to do to run the jar file in centos 5 . maybe I need to install JDBC drivers via repo or ...

Comment: You just download it from the mysql site and add it to the classpath of your application. In general JDBC drivers are not 'installed' in any way.

Comment: i added that to app.  but the same jar file work in contos 6 and dont work in centos 5.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Do you get an exception? Off so post the stacktrace.